# LT1677CN8 alternative?

Tags: operational-amplifier

we are trying to build the K&J Magnetics Seismometer in my physics class and we are having trouble getting the LT1677. It's not available at the moment. What can we substitute in place of the LT1677 in the following circuit?

[K&J Magnetics Seismometer](https://www.instructables.com/id/DIY-Seismometer/)

[image]

Comment: You will have a difficult time finding a "jelly bean" op-amp in a DIP package offering comparable performance to the LT1677. I would just solder the LT1677CS8 (SOIC package) to a [breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1212).

Comment: No Cross but looks like Digi-Key has stock on the part you are looking for. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/linear-technology-analog-devices/LT1677CN8-PBF/LT1677CN8-PBF-ND/962980

Answer (score 1):

The LT1677 is a low-noise, rail-rail, precision* operational amplifier.

Looking at the circuit, I think you need the low-noise part first, and maybe the rail-rail part.  Based on the circuit you show, bias is taken care of, and based on the link that shows the output coming from a coil, the input impedance to the amp is small.  So the most important parameter is the voltage noise.

So -- anything that is rail-rail, works at 5V, and has voltage noise roughly that low.  If you're in a pinch, you can probably use any rail-rail amp, or even an LM358 if you adjust for the pinout and set the center voltage a bit lower by adjusting R4 and R5 (I'd aim for 1.8V with a 5V supply).

* Ever notice how they're *all* "precision"?

Comment: What am I supposed to do when I need an imprecision op amp‽

Comment: The LM741 is the de-facto standard "imprecision" op-amp. :)

Comment: I don't know!  Fortunately I've never faced that problem.

Comment: There are multiple op-amp technologies: "general-purpose" usually encompasses low-power (and low performance) op-amps; "high speed" op-amps are just that, but typically introduce large DC errors and have stability issues; and "precision" op-amps are generally slower, have extremely low DC offsets, very high gain, and also can have stability issues (due to input capacitance).

Comment: its tough to find opamps with lower than 1nanoVoltRMSinput-referred-noise. But easy to use discrete JFETS or bipolars to get lower. You just have to work with (much) higher input-offset-voltages.